# Node.js http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I have the following code that requests the Google.com homepage and sends the page data back to an Iframe on the client side.

```
 var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    var pageData = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      pageData += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
      response.send(pageData)
    });
  });
```

However, all images and CSS are broken in the iframe? How can I preserve the images and CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add <base href="http://google.com/"> to the html. Preferably in the head, so do string replace on '<head>' and replace in with '<head><base href="http://google.com/">'

Comment: PS. you probably also have to strip the JS, because AJAX won't work cross origin.

Comment: Hm, I've never seen that before.... Sounds reasonable, I'm going to give it a shot, thank you ; )

Comment: Dude, you saved me another week of wanting to bang my head against my monitor. Thank you, a thousand times thank you.

Comment: You're a thousand times welcome. I think your monitor will be pleased :-)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to have the client fetch the Google page?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  var nif = document.createElement("iframe");
  nif.width = 850;
  nif.height = 500;
  nif.src = "http://www.google.de";
  nif.appendChild( document.createTextNode("no iframe support") );
  document.body.appendChild(nif);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>IFRAME</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I failed to mention that I'm on the server side making the request via Node js.

Comment: Sure, I noticed; I just didn't understand why when it is easier on the client side. Well, there may be a reason ... just couldn't figure out what it could be.

Comment: Actually, I now see how your solution is viable. I'm going to give this a shot also.

Comment: Good. :) And of course you can hardcode the IFRAME, making it even easier - if that's allowed by the problem's constraints.